# How to access system preferences in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: system-settings

Recently had to install Ubuntu 12.04 as my previous Ubuntu which I'd used for 3 years stopped working. I'm finding 12.04 extremely frustrating, I can't seem to access anything, for example now I'm trying to get to System preferences, so I can change ibus preferences.

I checked the answers which were already given on this forum for the question *How do I find “system > preferences”*

However, the answers that were given just tell how to find System Settings - well, that is easy, there is a tab for System Settings on this 12.04, but amazingly System Settings does not seem to have System Preferences or most of the other things one would reasonably expect to find under Settings! It only has tabs for things like Appearance, Keyboard, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I know it seems strange that ibus settings are not under 'System Settings' but you can open the dash and type ibus and it will come up.

Alternatively you'll find all your 'System Preferences' applications in the Dash by navigating to the 'Applications view' (little icon on the bottom displaying a ruler and two brushes) then click on 'Filter Results' and then toggle 'System'.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I finally managed it using dash as you suggested. Since I installed 12.04 there are so many problems - it crashes constantly, and whereas before I had no difficulty transferring files of many GB, between external hard drives, etc., now transferring something of just a few hundred MB makes the whole system go into conniptions and freeze up. The previous ubuntu had fatally crashed and after trying all the solutions for that I could find just gave up and installed this version, but I suppose the old one must be buried in the system and maybe that is also slowing everything down?

Comment: that could be possible, yes. I actually prefer to do fresh installs rather than upgrades for the exact same reasons. If you feel that 12.04 is somewhat slow and buggy for you I'd suggest trying 13.04. Even though it isn't an LTS version I've experienced it to be a lot faster and more stable than 12.04. Again I'd prefer a fresh install.

Comment: It is a fresh install (did it from within Windows), there was no way to even get into my previously installed version anymore (I don't know which edition it was, but started in 2010), I'm just thinking that everything from the previous version is still in the computer taking up space without being accessible? If I now install 13.04 will both previous versions be haunting the system or does everything get recycled? My preference would be to get my old ubuntu back, if that were possible.

Comment: Ah I see. It is not advised to use Wubi to install ubuntu from within windows anymore (they even removed that option from the newest version). The easiest way to check if your old partition is still there and recover the data on it would be starting ubuntu from a usb stick (i.e. hit 'Try Ubuntu' from the install menu) and mount your harddrive from there. Every partition should be displayed in your filemanager as an external device. If you have anymore questions regarding that topic please ask a seperate question cause this wanders off from your original problem quite a bit.